# IBM MQ XMS - Subscribe to multiple Topics in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, xms

Is there a way to use the asterisk (*) syntax to subscribe to all the topics that are reports ?

For example: "MyData\version1.0\Reports\(*)"

p.s : I'm using xms.

```
class MyXmsApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyXmsApp app = new MyXmsApp();
        app.Setup();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        XMSFactoryFactory xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
        IConnectionFactory cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
        cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "CLIENT");
        cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM_LOCAL");
        cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V1);

        IConnection conn = cf.CreateConnection();
        Console.WriteLine("connection created");
        ISession sess = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
        IDestination dest = sess.CreateQueue("queue://q");
        IMessageConsumer consumer = sess.CreateConsumer(dest);
        MessageListener ml = new MessageListener(OnMessage);
        consumer.MessageListener = ml;
        conn.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Consumer started");
    }

    private void OnMessage(IMessage msg)
    {
        ITextMessage textMsg = (ITextMessage)msg;
        Console.Write("Got a message: ");
        Console.WriteLine(textMsg.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard character you want in MQ pub/sub is '#'. In your example subscribing to the topic string:

MyData/version1.0/Reports/#

Would subscribe to:
MyData/version1.0/Reports/DailyReport
MyData/version1.0/Reports/WeeklyReport
MyData/version1.0/Reports/MonthlyReport

More information here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pla.doc/q005010_.htm